# Свои операторы в своей структуре питон? ч2

Tags: python, ооп, операторы

Опять таки, предположим есть класс v2:

```
class v2:
    x: int
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x; self.y = y
```

Для него я хотел создать операторы, и после немногих проб и ошибок и вопроса здесь, я пришел к такому написанию:

```
class v2:
    x: int
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return v2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x 
        self.y += other.y
```

**"__add__ для вектор_1 = вектор_2 + вектор3, а __iadd__ для вектор_1 += вектор_2"**
Но в первом случае работает все правильно, а во-втором:

```
v_1 = v2()
v_2 = v2()
v_1 += v_2
print(v_1)

# Вывод: None
```

Где я опять ошибся?

Comment: А гуглом пробовали пользоваться  "перегрузка операторов python"? https://www.codecamp.ru/blog/python-overloading/

Comment: добавьте return self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы используете оператор `+=`, Python ожидает, что метод `__iadd__` вернет обновленный объект после выполнения операции. В вашем случае, когда вы пытались использовать `+=`, метод `__iadd__` не возвращал сам объект, из-за чего результат операции оказывался `None`.

Изменил ваш метод `__iadd__`, чтобы он работал как нужно:

```py
class v2:
    x: int
    y: int
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return v2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x 
        self.y += other.y
        return self  # Теперь метод возвращает объект после изменения
```

Теперь, когда вы напишете `v_1 += v_2`, объект `v_1` будет обновлен и в тот же момент возвращен, так что `print(v_1)` покажет результат изменений, а не `None`